# How to define a function that returns a type class?

Tags: c++, function, cygwin, return-type

So I'm making a program for class and I have a header file called "Item" and I have a class inside my main file called "Room" and I'm trying to make a method that returns type Item and Cygwin is giving me pages and pages of errors!

Here's my code so far:

Item Header File:

```
class Item
{
    std::string description;

    public: Item (std::string newDescription)
    {
        description = newDescription;
    }

    public: std::string getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
};
```

Here's the main Class:

```
        #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "Item.h"

    class Room
    {
        std::string description;
        int exits[2][4];
        std::string items[10];

        Room(std::string description)
        {
            this -> description = description;
        }

        void setExit (int direction, int neighbor) //Direction - 1=N, 2=E, 3=S, 4-W
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (exits[0][i] == NULL)
                {
                    exits[0][i] = neighbor;
                    exits[1][i] = direction;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        std::string getShortDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        std::string getLongDescription()
        {
            return "You are " + description + ".\n" + getExitString();
        }

        std::string getExitString()
        {
            std::string returnString = "Exits:";

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (exits[1][i] != NULL)
                {
                    std::string tempDirection;

                    switch(exits[1][i])
                    {
                        case 1: tempDirection = "North";
                                break;

                        case 2: tempDirection = "East";
                                break;

                        case 3: tempDirection = "South";
                                break;

                        case 4: tempDirection = "West";
                                break;
                    }

                    returnString += " " + tempDirection;
                }

                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            returnString += "\nItems in the room:\n";
            //returnString += getRoomItems();
            return returnString;
        }

        /*Item getItem(std::string itemName)
        {
            int size = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (items[i] == NULL)
                {
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    size++;
                }   
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (items[i] == itemName)
                {
                    return items[i];
                }
            }
        }*/

        int getExit(int direction)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if (exits[1][i] == direction)
                {
                    return exits[0][i];
                }
            }
        }
    };

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

    }
```

Putting the error on here will take forever so I'm going to skip it sorry!

Any help would be super helpful!

Comment: *"Putting the error on here will take forever"* -- I am voting to close this question because it does not contain a specific error. At least post *something*. Tell us what line the error is on, and maybe at least the first error from the compiler.

Comment: Your function `getItem` which supposedly is returning an `Item` is actually returning a `std::string`. also that function may not even return anything in some cases.

Comment: c++ is different from Java. Throw that attitude overboard!

Comment: Nobody will help if you don't state the error.  How about looking at the *first* error, and seeing if that makes any sense by itself?

Comment: @UnholySheep But `Item` contains a non-explicit constructor that takes `std::string` so `return items[i]` is actually going to do `return Item(items[i])` implicitly. Two wrongs make a right, sometimes!

Comment: Are you sure you are writing in C++?  The use of `public:` is fishy.

Comment: @jdlugosz It's syntactically correct C++, if formatted a bit unusually.

Comment: passing strings by value, not using const, not using initialization syntax in ctor, using NULL (as an int?!), using comments in lieu of enumeration type,  ... you need someone in person to show you how to write that, mapping your ideas to proper C++ usage so you learn it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your proposed implementation of this method:

```
Item getItem(std::string itemName)
{
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // items[i] is of type std::string, which is a value type, not a pointer. It
        // makes no sense to compare it to null, because it can't even be null.
        if (items[i] == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            size++;
        }   
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (items[i] == itemName)
        {
            // Here you return an std::string, not an Item -- however, Item contains
            // a one-argument constructor accepting std::string and is not marked
            // "explicit", so this line is equivalent to "return Item(items[i]);".
            // This may or may not be what you intended, but would not cause a
            // compile-time error.
            return items[i];
        }
    }

    // You do not return anything if program flow makes it to this point. This
    // causes an undefined value to be returned, and you don't want that. You need
    // to return something here -- but it can't be null, because Item is a value
    // type!
}
```

Consider instead using `std::vector<std::string>` as the type of `items`.  A vector is a variable-length container that can grow automatically.  (Think Java's `List<>`.)  Or, perhaps you want to *map* item names to `Item` instances, in which case you might use `std::map<std::string, Item>`.